# how to resolve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to access all the data from database "listOfFolder" table "folder" and want to store the data in a string array folders[] but i am getting  how to resolve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
try{

  mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("listOfFolder", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

int count = 0;
String folders[] = null;
Cursor folderCursor = mydb.query("folder", null, null, null, null, null, null); 
while(folderCursor.moveToNext()) {

  folders[count] = folderCursor.getString(folderCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    count++;
}

ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DropboxActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,folders);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
setContentView(R.layout.listoffolder);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
String folders[] = null;
Cursor folderCursor = mydb.query("folder", null, null, null, null, null, null); 
while(folderCursor.moveToNext()){
    folders[count] = folderCursor.getString(folderCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    count++;
}
```

to

```
Cursor folderCursor = mydb.query("folder", null, null, null, null, null, null);
if (folderCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String folders[] = new String[folderCursor.getCount()];
    do {
        folders[count] = folderCursor.getString(folderCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        count++;
    } while(folderCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: after that i am trying to create a listview and again i am getting nullpointerexception there ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DropboxActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,folders);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           setContentView(R.layout.listoffolder);

Comment: getting null pointer exception at 
           list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Possibly `findViewById` can't find your ListView. Are you sure there is a ListView with id `@+id/lv` in your layout xml file?

Comment: yes i have a layout name listoffolder and i have use a list view there with id lv

Comment: i got where the error was i have to use setContentView(R.layout.listoffolder); before ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
String folders[] = null;
```

What did you expect to happen?

This code is a bad idea, because you have no idea how large a set the query will bring back.  You have to call `new` to allocate a large enough array.

I'd prefer a collection like a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) if it's available to you.  Check [this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/) one out, too.

Comment: how do i store the data in a List

Comment: See my edit.  And see about getting Google installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ArrayList<datatypehere> namehere=new ArrayList<datatypehere>();
```

Then you can add elements to the list by:

```
String example1 = "this is a string";
namehere.add(example1);
```

Theres quite abit on lists in the JavaDocs and Java Tutorials if you search for them.